# xamarin forms finding Listview height

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using a listview which can have N number of items and this N number keeps on changing.However the problem is that listview height doesn't change according to the number of items within listview.can  someone help to fix this height issue without giving a custom height.
Please do refer the sample code

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="myList"
                      SeparatorVisibility="None" 
                      HasUnevenRows = "true"
                      ItemSelected="OnListClicked">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                         <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding question}"
                                                TextColor="#5b5f66"
                                                FontSize="Medium"
                                                FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                                <Entry x:Name="AnswerEntry"
                                       Text="{Binding response,Mode=TwoWay}"  
                                       TextColor="#aaaaaa"
                                       FontSize="Medium"/>
                            </StackLayout>      
                          </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
      <Button HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
              VerticalOptions = "End" 
              Text="SAVE"
              TextColor="#fff"
              FontSize="Small"
              BackgroundColor="#FFAF00"
              Clicked="OnButtonClicked"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your code here.. whatever you have tried..

Comment: are your cells the same size? is the listview inside stacklayout?

Comment: @MichałŻołnieruk Yes, the listview is inside the StackLayout and the cell size differs.

Comment: The listview size is not supposed to change. It haves the scroll capability. Are you trying to increase the listview height on each item addition?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza.I  am not trying to change the size and I knew it does have scroll capability,but I need to know the approximate height of ListView.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView
              HasUnevenRows="False"
              RowHeight="20"
              SeparatorVisibility="None" 
              BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
              x:Name="pickerlist"
              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False"
              IsRefreshing="False">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Picker x:Name="pickername" 
                      VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                      SelectedItem="picselect"  
                      BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                      TextColor="Black"
                      SelectedIndexChanged="selecindex"
                      Title="{Binding QuestionName}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding .Answers }" 
                      ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding AnswerName}">
                                </Picker>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```